# python element of class copied accros new instances

Tags: python, attributes, copy, instance

I have class named `KSlamComp` that read numbers from a file and put it in two attributes `gt_raw` and `slam_raw`

```
class KSlamComp:
    def __init__(self, forward_nodes_lookup = 1, backward_nodes_lookup = 0, slam_input_raw = data.Data(), gt_input_raw = data.Data()):
        self.slam_raw = slam_input_raw
        self.gt_raw = gt_input_raw
        self.nb_node_forward = forward_nodes_lookup
        self.nb_node_backward = backward_nodes_lookup

    def read(self, file_name):
        assert(len(self.slam_raw.posetime) == 0)
        f = open(file_name, 'r')
        for line in f:
            print("line")
            assert len(line.split()) == 8

            slampose = data.Pose(data.Point( float(line.split()[0]), float(line.split()[1] )),  float(line.split()[2]))
            gtpose = data.Pose(data.Point( float(line.split()[4]), float(line.split()[5] )),  float(line.split()[6]))

            self.slam_raw.posetime.append( (slampose, float(line.split()[3]) ) )
            self.gt_raw.posetime.append( (gtpose, float(line.split()[7]) ) )


    def printraw(self):
        print("Printing Raw data")
        for x in range(0, len(self.slam_raw.posetime)):
            print(str(self.slam_raw.posetime[x][0].getPosition().x) + " " \
                + str(self.slam_raw.posetime[x][0].getPosition().y) + " " \
                + str(self.slam_raw.posetime[x][0].getOrientation()) + " " \
                + str(self.slam_raw.posetime[x][1]) + " " + \
                  str(self.gt_raw.posetime[x][0].getPosition().x) + " " \
                + str(self.gt_raw.posetime[x][0].getPosition().y) + " " \
                + str(self.gt_raw.posetime[x][0].getOrientation()) + " " \
                + str(self.gt_raw.posetime[x][1]))
        print("\n")
```

The `Data` is simply something along those lines

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        #Tuple with pose and time 
        self.posetime = list()
```

Now I have this test file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kslamcomp import data
from kslamcomp import kslamcomp

def main():
    # parse command line options
    d = kslamcomp.KSlamComp(1, 0)
    d.read("data_files/shifted.txt")
    d.printraw()
    d.print()

    d_invert = kslamcomp.KSlamComp()
    d_invert.printraw()
    d.printraw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My understanding was that d_invert is a new object KSlamComp with all attribute initialised to their default value. Especially, `self.slam_raw` and `self.gt_raw` are empty `Data` objects with empty lists. Hoever when I run this program, I have

```
$ python3 test_sanity.py 
line
line
line
line
Printing Raw data
1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 6.0
5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 8.0 8.0 7.1 14.0
9.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 11.0 2.0
13.0 13.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 15.0 15.0 10.0


Printing Raw data
1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 6.0
5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 8.0 8.0 7.1 14.0
9.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 11.0 2.0
13.0 13.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 15.0 15.0 10.0


Printing Raw data
1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 6.0
5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 8.0 8.0 7.1 14.0
9.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 11.0 2.0
13.0 13.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 15.0 15.0 10.0
```

While I thought the second print whould have been empty it seems to contain the data that was read in the first `KSlamComp` object.

Why are `slef.gt_raw` and `Self.slam_raw` the same object in both object ? If I initialised them "manually" by calling `d_invert = kslamcomp.KSlamComp(0, 1, data.Data(), data.Data())` it seems to work but I thought that having the default parameter was the same.

Comment: A famous gotcha: Using mutable datastructures as default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use mutable objects as a defaults of function, because defaults are stored inside a function object.
I would probably write

```
class KSlamComp:
    def __init__(..., slam_input_raw = None, gt_input_raw = None, ...) 
        self.slam_raw = slam_input_raw or data.Data()
        self.gt_stuff = gt_input_raw or data.Data()
```